Medieval fantasy movie about a clock and running out of time
So I have been trying to figure out this movie for ages, so if anyone can help that would be great! The movie is from the 90s roughly and it is set back in medievalish times, there is a huge clock and a prince and princess (it's not the princess bride) and the clock starts to speed up which speeds up time. They have to stop the clock from speeding up time before they die.
If anyone could help that would be great! As I said it is definitely not the princess bride.
Thanks 

Possibly To the Ends of Time From 1996. From an online synopsis:

There is long war in fairy country and no-one can win it. One day King Francis gets [a] weapon, that can stop the war – “the clock of time”, which can speed up time. But, as always happens in fairy tales, the weapon [falls into] evil sorceress Karnissa’ hands. And there is only two people, who can save world from [the] sorceress – brave Princess Stephanie and her lover James.

Here's the trailer:



